# Coinbase Api Java POST request "Invalid Signature"

Tags: java, post, bitcoin, signature, coinbase-api

I am trying to send a POST request to the coinbase sandbox endpoint. When signing the request I always get an "Invalid Signature" response. It seems that coinbase requires the JSON message be base 64 encoded and sent as a part of the signature. I am fairly new to POST requests and have never signed a message before. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have been stuck on this issue for a week so any input is much appreciated.

The relevant part of my code is below

```
public void postOrder() throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CloneNotSupportedException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    String message = "{ \n"+
               " \"size\":\"1.00\", \n"+
               " \"price\":\"0.80\", \n"+
               " \"side\":\"buy\", \n"+
               " \"product_id\":\"BTC-USD\" \n"+
               "}"; 

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
    message = json.toString();
    try
    {
            String timestamp= Instant.now().getEpochSecond()+"";
            String accessSign = getAccess(timestamp,"POST","/orders",message);
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("key");
            String passphrase = properties.getProperty("passphrase");

            URL url = new URL("https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/orders");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey);
            connection.setRequestProperty("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", accessSign);
            connection.setRequestProperty("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            connection.setRequestProperty("CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", passphrase);
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java Client"); 

          try { 
            connection.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream(); 
            output.write(param.getBytes("UTF-8"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }

          String status = connection.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("STATUS: "+status);  

     }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     return;
}


 private String getAccess(String timestamp, String method, String path, String param) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, CloneNotSupportedException, IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String secretKeyString = properties.getProperty("secret");

        String prehash = timestamp+method+path+param;
        byte[] secretKeyDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKeyString);
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyDecoded, "HmacSHA256");
        Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        hmacSha256.init(secretKey);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes()));
 }
```

Comment: can you share how you ended up fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with using javax.crypto.* library functions. The changes I did were

- Took the API Key for the sandbox.
- To encoded the signature, I explicitly used UTF_8

Below is the code that worked for me with Coinbase sandbox API_KEY -

```
 public String getCoinbaseHeaderSignature(
        String timeStamp, 
        String method,
        String requestPath,
        String body
) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    String data = timeStamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath + body;

    byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(API_KEY);

    SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");

    // Get HmacSHA256 instance 
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    mac.init(keySpec);

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

}
```

*For more details, refer to documentation* https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-key-authentication

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I utilized [gdax-java](https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java) example. I solved this issue by removing decimal values from timestamp that means I just used integer part of the timestamp value.