# How to properly sign requests to Coinbase V2 API using API KEY Authentication in Java

Tags: java, signature, api-key, coinbase-api, secret-key

I'm developing a java wrapper for the coinbase v2 API because I can't find any library that works the way I want : in a "fluent" way, using vavr data types & apiKey authentication.

First of all I developed the whole public data wrapper of the coinbase API, and it works fine. It allow me to call for Coinbase currencies, ExchangeRates, prices...

Now I want to call secured endpoints like `https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user`. Si I followed specs defined in https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication

So far nothing crazy, I simply follow guidelines, even if there are not based on java but on python, ruby and nodejs it doesn't look really hard... But when I execute a call to an endpoint, for exemple : `https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user` I get this response :

```json
"errors":[
  {
    "id": "authentication_error",
    "message": "invalid signature"
  }
]
```

So I decided to make some research cause I was thinking I'm wrong with my signature process. So I found a lot of unofficial java & C# wrappers and watched how they all did, and it looks a lot like what I do in my code... But it doesn't matter, I took the different codes I found and adapted them to my case so that they fit into my code. And then, after implementing 6 different ways to sign my requests, it still no working.

There is my six different not working ways to implements api key authentication for the coinbase API :

```java
    public String[] getAuthenticationHeaders(
      final String apiKey,
      final String secret,
      final long timestamp,
      final String httpMethod,
      final String httpPath,
      final String httpBody) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(apiKey) || StringUtils.isBlank(secret)) {
      manageNotAllowed(
          new JCoinbaseException(
              "You must specify an Api key and a secret to access this resource."));
    }

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 1
    var message = timestamp + httpMethod + httpPath + ((httpBody == null) ? "" : httpBody);
    var signature1 = new HmacUtils(HMAC_SHA_256, secret.getBytes()).hmacHex(message);

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 2
    var signature2 = HmacUtils.hmacSha256Hex(secret, message);

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 3
    var mac =
        HmacUtils.getInitializedMac("HmacSHA256", secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    mac.update(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    var signature3 = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, mac.doFinal()));

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 4
    String signature4 = "";
    try {
      String prehash = timestamp + httpMethod.toUpperCase() + httpPath + httpBody;
      byte[] secretDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
      SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secretDecoded, Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256").getAlgorithm());
      Mac sha256 = (Mac) Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      sha256.init(keyspec);
      signature4 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes()));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException(new Error("Cannot set up authentication headers."));
    }

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 5
    var hmacKey = secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    var messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    var hmac = HmacUtils.getInitializedMac("HmacSHA256", hmacKey);
    var sig = hmac.doFinal(messageBytes);
    char[] c = new char[sig.length * 2];
    int b;
    for(int i = 0; i < sig.length; i++){
      b = sig[i] >> 4;
      c[i * 2] = (char)(87 + b + (((b - 10) >> 31) & -39));
      b = sig[i] & 0xF;
      c[i * 2 + 1] = (char)(87 + b + (((b - 10) >> 31) & -39));
    }
    var signature5 = String.valueOf(c);

    //SIGNATURE VERSION 6
    var preHash = timestamp + httpMethod.toUpperCase() + httpPath + httpBody;
    byte[] secretDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec;
    Mac sha256 = null;
    try {
      keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretDecoded, Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256").getAlgorithm());
      sha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      sha256.init(keySpec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    var signature6 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256.doFinal(preHash.getBytes()));


    return new String[] {
      "CB-ACCESS-SIGN",
      signature6,
      "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP",
      String.valueOf(timestamp),
      "CB-ACCESS-KEY",
      apiKey,
      "Accept",
      "application/json"
    };
  }
```

As you can see, I have really tried, but it still not working, so I ask for you to help me, please :)

For a better understanding here are the different simplified code snippets of my wrapper that uses this signature process :

```java
//A RANDOM TESTING CLASS FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSE ONLY :)
@Test
void main() {
  JCoinbaseClient client = JCoinbaseClientFactory.build("myApiKey", "myApiSecret");
  var currentUser = client.user().fetchCurrentUser();
}

//JCoinbaseClient class
public UserService user() {
  var allowed = authService.allow(this);

  if (allowed.isLeft()) {
    manageNotAllowed(allowed.getLeft());
  }
   return userService;
}

//UserService class
public User fetchCurrentUser() {
  return service
      .fetchCurrentUser(client, authentication)
      .onSuccess(user -> log.info("Successfully fetch current user."))
      .onFailure(
          throwable ->
              manageOnFailure(
                  new JCoinbaseException(throwable),
                  "An error occurred while fetching current user",
                  throwable))
      .get();
}

//CoinbaseUserService class
public Try<User> fetchCurrentUser(final JCoinbaseClient client, final AuthenticationService authentication) {

  var requestHeaders =
      authentication.getAuthenticationHeaders(
          client.getProperties(), "GET", client.getProperties().getUserPath(), "");

  var request =
      HttpRequest.newBuilder()
          .GET()
          .uri(
              URI.create(
                  client.getProperties().getApiUrl() + client.getProperties().getUserPath()))
          .headers(requestHeaders)
          .build();

  return Try.of(() -> client.getClient().send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()))
      .mapTry(
          stringHttpResponse ->
              client
                  .getJsonSerDes()
                  .readValue(stringHttpResponse.body(), UserDto.class)
                  .toUser());
}

//AuthenticationService class
public String[] getAuthenticationHeaders(
    final JCoinbaseProperties properties,
    final String httpMethod,
    final String httpPath,
    final String httpBody) {
  return getAuthenticationHeaders(
      properties.getApiKey().getOrNull(),
      properties.getSecret().getOrNull(),
      getCurrentTime(),
      httpMethod,
      httpPath,
      httpBody);
}

public String[] getAuthenticationHeaders(
      final String apiKey,
      final String secret,
      final long timestamp,
      final String httpMethod,
      final String httpPath,
      final String httpBody) {
   // YOU CAN FIND THIS CODE IN THE FIRST CODE SNIPPET
}
```

And finally, the result in my console (the http error handling isn't developed yet. This is assumed)

```java
com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.exception.JCoinbaseException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "errors" (class com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.dto.UserDto), not marked as ignorable (15 known properties: "bitcoin_unit", "avatar_url", "created_at", "name", "resource", "profile_bio", "username", "profile_url", "id", "email", "time_zone", "profile_location", "resource_path", "native_currency", "country"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}"; line: 1, column: 73] (through reference chain: com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.dto.UserDto["errors"])

    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.UserService.lambda$fetchCurrentUser$1(UserService.java:26)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.onFailure(Try.java:659)
    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.UserService.fetchCurrentUser(UserService.java:24)
    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.UserServiceTest.main(UserServiceTest.java:59)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "errors" (class com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.dto.UserDto), not marked as ignorable (15 known properties: "bitcoin_unit", "avatar_url", "created_at", "name", "resource", "profile_bio", "username", "profile_url", "id", "email", "time_zone", "profile_location", "resource_path", "native_currency", "country"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}"; line: 1, column: 73] (through reference chain: com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.dto.UserDto["errors"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:987)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1974)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1686)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperties(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1390)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3516)
    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.CoinbaseUserService.lambda$fetchCurrentUser$faa3259$1(CoinbaseUserService.java:37)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.mapTry(Try.java:634)
    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.CoinbaseUserService.fetchCurrentUser(CoinbaseUserService.java:33)
    at com.github.badpop.jcoinbase.client.service.user.UserService.fetchCurrentUser(UserService.java:22)
    ... 66 more
```

If you have any idea, I'll take it !

NB: the wrapper code is accessible on github if you prefer : https://github.com/Bad-Pop/JCoinbase on the `feat/fetch-user-resources` git branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoded requestPath is just `/user` rather than `/v2/user`

According to the linked Spec:

> The requestPath is the full path and query parameters of the URL, e.g.: `/v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD.`

According to your source

```
//CoinbaseUserService.java:
public Try<User> fetchCurrentUser(final JCoinbaseClient client, final AuthenticationService authentication) {
    var requestHeaders = authentication.getAuthenticationHeaders(
        client.getProperties(), "GET",      client.getProperties().getUserPath()     , "");
    // ...

//JCoinbaseProperties.java:
private void extractProperties(final String apiKey, final String secret) { /*...*/
    this.userPath = properties.getProperty(    "coinbase.api.path.resource.user"    ); // ...

//jcoinbase.properties:
    coinbase.api.path.resource.user=/user
```

Comment: Damn it ! I could have searched a long time ! So the problem was between the chair and the keyboard... I feel so stupid now :') Thanks a lot! You just saved me a lot of time !!!!!!!! we can never say it enough : RTFM

Comment: @Bad_Pop Haha, all good dude, you're definitely not stupid, sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes. I just happen to be pretty good at catching this sort of stuff! It looks like you *did* RTFM (which is way more than can be said for many others..) but just barely missed what you needed. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you @xtratic for your comment, It makes me happy !!!! Yeah, don't worry, I'm not giving up !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71908952/4564749 I was able to resolve Invalid Signature by the similar method that you have used.